# Does size of the jar file affect the performance of AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suppose I have bundled many third party jar files with my jar and only few of them are being used.
Is it going to affect  the performance of my lambda function? 
Like initialization for my function will be slower? 
How does AWS initializes the containers for a lambda function behind the scenes?

Comment: This is a good watch for Java runtime Lambda functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddg1u5HLwg8

Answer (score 0):

Each Lambda function runs in its own container. When a function is created, Lambda packages it into a new container and then executes that container on a multi-tenant cluster of machines managed by AWS. Before the functions start running, each function’s container is allocated its necessary RAM and CPU capacity. Once the functions finish running, the RAM allocated at the beginning is multiplied by the amount of time the function spent running. The customers then get charged based on the allocated memory and the amount of run time the function took to complete.

The entire infrastructure layer of AWS Lambda is managed by AWS. Customers don’t get much visibility into how the system operates, but they also don’t need to worry about updating the underlying machines, avoiding network contention, and so on—AWS takes care of this itself.

For detailed information on how lambda works and will jar size impact performance, refer following links:

https://www.serverless.com/aws-lambda/#:~:text=Each%20Lambda%20function%20runs%20in,necessary%20RAM%20and%20CPU%20capacity.

https://blog.octo.com/en/cold-start-warm-start-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: We were able to reduce the jar file size from 40MB to 9MB and we didn't see much difference in response but we had to increase the memory size from 512MB to 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

The next paragraph is from [best practices documentation of aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html)

> Minimize your deployment package size to its runtime necessities. This will reduce the amount of time that it takes for your deployment package to be downloaded and unpacked ahead of invocation. For functions authored in Java or .NET Core, avoid uploading the entire AWS SDK library as part of your deployment package. Instead, selectively depend on the modules which pick up components of the SDK you need.

You shouldn't be including unused dependencies in your package. In addition to that; please check lambda layers which is used to keep your deployment package small, which makes development easier. Here is the sample project for [java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/master/sample-apps/blank-java)

Comment: Jar file size didn't matter much after increasing the memory size for lambda functions. I think Node js is better option that java because of the lesser memory imprint, not sure about Python. We rewrote a function in Node js and it was fast even with minimal memory like <  300MB